# update manager tried to install older kernel 3.2.0.65 when 3.2.0.66 is already installed

Tags: update-manager

Yesterday, then again today, Update Manager wanted to install kernel 3.2.0.65, when I already have 3.2.0.66 installed and working in my 12.04 Ubuntu installation.  What's going on?

Clarification: I install all applicable updates via the Update-Manager as they come up.  That's how 3.2.0.66 was installed.  I don't want to remove anything, I just don't want Update-Manager to install an older kernel, or if for some reason that should be done, I'd like to know why.  Usually, I just install whatever I need to stay up-to-date.  Now I have to uncheck 3.2.0.65 kernel, headers, etc. updates every time Update Manager comes up.  I'd like to know why this is happening, and how to correct it so it doesn't happen any more.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have synaptic  package manager .
 install synaptic package manager.

```
$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

open it search in the quick filter for

```
linux-image
```

right click the kernel that you are wanting to keep '3.13.0-30.54'
mark for upgrade
right click on the kernel that you want to remove '3.13.0-30.54'
mark for removale & lock it by clicking in the menu package => lock version => uncheck auto install

then click on apply

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

pic : [image: finding the kernel version]